# View expired - commit action anyway?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is there a way to work around ViewExpiredException to commit an action anyway?

Via richfaces' a4j:actionparam I set all required information into my backing bean. Unless the view expires this works well.

When the view *is* expired the user is redirected to an error page and redirected back to the page where he was. Unfortunately his input is gone and he has to type it again. For longer, more elaborate comments this can become frustrating.

Ideas what could work, I don't have an idea of how to achieve any of them, though:

- transparently restore view in background and automatically retry action
- commit action without restoring view, redirect to new view of same page afterwards
- restore user input after -> error page -> input page redirects

Is there another way I'm missing?

Shortened, simplified JSF snippet:

```
<!-- within iteration over myBean.items as item -->
<h:inputTextarea value="#{myBean.comment}"/>
<a4j:commandButton action="#{myBean.addComment}">
    <a4j:actionparam value="#{item.id}" assignTo="#{myBean.selectedItemId}"/>
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Software stack: richfaces 3.3.3, myfaces 2.0.x, prettyfaces

Note: at least currently I don't need to care about XSS for this form. There is easier access to the functionality without requiring a valid view state.

Comment: You could take a look at the idea described in the following blog - http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/ImplementingGracefulSessionTimeoutWithSeamJSFAndJQuery

Comment: Thanks, but this won't help. My problem is not session timeout but losing view state. View state is stored server side and I don't see a pattern when it is discarded. I realize that I should probably fix unwanted view expiration instead of fixing symptoms.